# Error in upgrading an asp.net 5 project to .net 6 : "Conflicting assets with the same target path"

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, upgrade, .net-6.0

I upgraded my existing ASP.NET 5 project to ASP.NET 6, and now after I build it, I'm getting the following error :

[image: conflicting assets]

My project was in ASP.NET 5 and now is ASP.NET 6 contains some razor pages alongside AngularJS typescript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was fixed after upgrading Visual Studio to v17.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I have started maintaining a codebase that has not been built for several months. It uses Blazor. I updated everything to .net6.0 and I got the error described by the OP even though I am using VS version 17.3.6. I think in my case the cause is different and is due to using Blazor in a wasm project used as a shared library. This configuration is discussed [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-preview-4:-Blazor-project-issues/1530974) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36732).

The solution I found was to exclude copy for the files causing the issue, by using `DefaultItemExcludes` in the project file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
...
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);wwwroot\mydir\*.*</DefaultItemExcludes> 
<PropertyGroup>
```

I found the solution when preparing to create a new razor library as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). I spent a considerable amount of time on this issue so I hope this solution and the associated links are of use to others.

Note that the solution means that the files are now not copied to the build project; however, this can be solved by either adding a post-build xcopy step or moving the assets to the application project and maintaining them there.